# callback of static method call

Tags: php, static

I have:

```
function sayName($param)
{
    echo $param();
}

class Robin
{
    public static $name = "Robin Webber";
    public static function bearName()
    {
        echo static::$name;
    }
}

sayName(array("Robin", 'bearName'));
```

This code is a little counter intuitive to me.

How exactly does passing an array to `sayNam()` call the static method of the class `Robin`?

Any references to PHP documentation on this behavior for examination would be helpful.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score -1):

Do it:

```
function sayName(array $params)
{
  $class = array_shift($params);
  $method = array_shift($params);

  call_user_func_array($class.'::'.$method,array());

  // or call_user_func($class.'::'.$method);
}

class Robin
{
  public static $name = "Robin Webber";

  public static function bearName()
  {
     echo static::$name;
  }
}

sayName(array("Robin", 'bearName'));
//Robin Webber
```

See more [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Comment: This does not answer the question. They were asking about the behavior of using arrays as callbacks. Also, this is not the only way of using static method callables.

Comment: "This does not answer the question..." Then what is this :)? I helped with issue and gave links."..using arrays as callbacks.." - what is nonsense???

Comment: @ajshort if you didnt understand: OP code doesnt works, and he asks - "how I can do it?"